# Vimeo on iOS5 using MPMoviePlayerController won't load video

Tags: iphone, video, ios5, html5-video, vimeo

The following code loads a Vimeo vide just fine in a webview, but the user has to click the play
button to start

```
    VidViewController *webScrollView = 
    [[VidViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VidViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/36120576"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    webScrollView.request = request;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webScrollView animated:YES];
    [webScrollView release];
```

I would like to get MPMoviePlayerController to work, but can't get the video to load.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/36120576"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
    initWithContentURL:audioURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:player];


        [player play];    

}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    removeObserver:self
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:player];    
    [player autorelease];    
}
```

There isn't much support on developer.apple

Comment: Well the url `http://player.vimeo.com/video/36120576` points to flash file. `MPMoviePlayerController` can't play flash files.

Comment: Why would it play in the browser then?

Comment: Did some more research, the URL really loads a webpage, which will detect support for flash, if no flash is availble then it will load a HTML5 version of the video.